# Fineuploader fileState Type Error on cancel/cancelAll/reset

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I am building some upload functionality into an app using FineUploaderBasic.  All is well and good apart from when I try to cancel a file (when a condition is met during the onupload callback). I get this error:

TypeError: fileState[id] is undefined
...var fileOrBlob = fileState[id].file || fileState[id].blobData.blob,

The onupload callback parameters id is 0 and the name is the correct name of the file.  It kind of makes sense that there isn't alot of fileState information at this point because the onupload process runs before the upload - so why does reset or cancel* still get this far...

How should I be cancelling a file (or files) or how do I reset the uploader at will.

N.B. I should also add that the error isn't fatal - in fact the functionality even looks like its works okay- but the error in the log isn't great to have.

Code Excerpt:

```
function UploadButton(element, opts)
{
    this.fineUploaderInst = null;
    this.opts = opts;
    this.element = element;
    var container = this;
    var originalBorder = null;
    var uploader = null;

    this.element.addClass("qq-upload-button");

    this.applyFineUploader = function() {
        this.uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
            button: this.element[0],
            request: {
                endpoint: "/files/fine-uploader"
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions : this.opts.extensions
            },
            multiple: false,
            callbacks: {
                onSubmit: function() {
                    container.element.find("span.ui-icon")
                        .removeClass("ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n")
                        .addClass("file-uploading");
                },
                onUpload: (opts.onUpload)
                    ? function(id, name) {
                        if(! container.opts.onUpload(id, name)) {
                            container.uploader.reset();
                        }

                        container.element.find("span.ui-icon")
                            .addClass("ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n")
                            .removeClass("file-uploading");
                    }
                    : function(id, name) {},
//... more stuff ...
```

Sorry about the untidiness of the excerpt above.  The variable *element* is coming in as a jQuery selector result and *opts* is just a simple dictionary of options.  I hope it helps.

I am using FineUploader 3.4.1.

Thanks people.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Also, list the version of fine Uploader you are using.

Comment: You are resetting the uploader in one of your callbacks?  Why?

Comment: For the reason that I need to run some extra validation before the upload goes ahead, the opts.onUpload is the validation bit which must evaluate to true.

Comment: The reset API method is not meant to cancel an upload.  You should be using the cancel API method.  In fact, you shouldn't be using cancel at all if you simply want to prevent a specific file from being uploaded.  Have a look at the `onValidate` [callbacks](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/callbacks.md) in the documentation.

Comment: Cheers, this sounds like the answer (don't know how I missed it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my last comment, please use either the `onValidate` or `onValidateBatch` callbacks to perform additional validation.  You can return false in these callbacks to instruct Fine Uploader to ignore the file (`onValidate`) or all files in the batch (`onValidateBatch`).  Please see the [callbacks documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/callbacks.html) for more details on these and other callbacks.

Comment: The key part which I was missing was stopOnFirstInvalidFile option.  Setting this to true gave me the expected behaviour. Thanks author.

Comment: Ah yes, there's that potential option as well.  Please see the [validation options documentation](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/options-fineuploaderbasic.md#validation-option-properties) for more validation-related settings.